# go get results in 'terminal prompts disabled' error for github private repo

Tags: git, go

I created the private repo examplesite/myprivaterepo using the Github UI from my browser.

Then I went to my go directory (on the desktop) and cloned it:

```
$ cd $GOPATH
$ go get github.com/examplesite/myprivaterepo
```

So far so good. Created the file scheduler.go, added to repo, and pushed.

```
$ vim scheduler.go
$ git add scheduler.go
$ git commit
$ git push
```

Everythng's OK. But when I went to a clean laptop  and tried to clone the repo, I got an error:

```
# Now on laptop, which doesn't yet know about the repo
$ cd $GOPATH
$ go get github.com/examplesite/myprivaterepo
# At this point it should ask for my user ID and password ,right? But it doesn't.
# Instead, this error occurs:
cd .; git clone https://github.com/examplesite/myprivaterepo /Users/tom/go/src/github.com/examplesite/myprivaterepo
Cloning into '/Users/tom/go/src/github.com/examplesite/myprivaterepo'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
package github.com/examplesite/myprivaterepo: exit status 128
```

Why is my laptop hating on my own repo and how can I get it to accept its fate? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a `go` error, `git` is returning "terminal prompts disabled". Can you run `git clone https://github.com/examplesite/myprivaterepo` on your laptop?

Comment: Thank you. The git clone worked. Then the go get worked. What's the deal? Do I have to "prime the pump" like this every time or did I misconfigure something?

Comment: @tomcam, you can add ssh keys to github account and go get will work from the start, see https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: @alexvasi: that only works if he clones the repo himself over ssh first, since it will request from `https://github.com/` if the import path doesn't exist. The git process should be able to prompt for the username/password, so there must be something different in the laptop configuration -- different shell, different .gitconfig, an env variable, etc.

Comment: All of this has helped me, but I'm not sure how to mark as answered and/or resolved. Here's what I have so far.

Comment: (Continued)

Not sure how to mark as answered and/or resolved because I am still not sure what the most robust solution is. Here's what I have so far.

@JimB suggested I use `git clone https://github.com/examplesite/myprivaterepo` and that worked, but I dont' quite understand why.

@alexvasi mentioned ssh keys. I have one already--but that's for my other Github account. I created a new ssh key & file:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@example.com" -f id_rsa_myuser_name`

Then copied that key into my private Github account. Maybe the best solution?

Comment: I usually work on Windows and I was having this problem. I added the "git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/" line to .gitconfig and SET the GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT variable to 1 but that did not work. Then I tried to import the package from my linux subsystem and it ran with no issues.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

It complains because it needs to use `ssh` instead of `https` but your git is still configured with https. so basically as others mentioned previously you need to either enable prompts or to configure git to use `ssh` instead of `https`. a simple way to do this by running the following:

```
git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

or if you already use `ssh` with `git` in your machine, you can safely edit `~/.gitconfig` and add the following line at the very bottom

**Note:** This covers all SVC, source version control, that depends on what you exactly use, github, gitlab, bitbucket)

```
# Enforce SSH
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/
[url "ssh://git@gitlab.com/"]
        insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
[url "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/"]
  insteadOf = https://bitbucket.org/
```

- If you want to keep password pompts disabled, you need to cache password. For more information on how to cache your github password on mac, windows or linux, please visit [this page](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-password-in-git).
- For more information on how to add ssh to your github account, please visit [this page](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/user/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

Also, more importantly, if this is a private repository for a company or for your self, you may need to skip using proxy or checksum database for such repos to avoid exposing them publicly.

To do this, you need to set `GOPRIVATE` environment variable that controls which modules the go command considers to be private (not available publicly) and should therefore **NOT** use the proxy or checksum database.

The variable is a comma-separated list of patterns (same syntax of Go's `path.Match`) of module path prefixes. For example,

```
export GOPRIVATE=*.corp.example.com,github.com/mycompany/*
```

Or

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/mycompany/*
```

- For more information on how to solve private packages/modules checksum validation issues, please read [this article](https://medium.com/mabar/today-i-learned-fix-go-get-private-repository-return-error-reading-sum-golang-org-lookup-93058a058dd8).
- For more information about go 13 modules and new enhancements, please check out [Go 1.13 Modules Release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#modules).

One last thing not to forget to mention, you can still configure `go get` to authenticate and fetch over `https`, all you need to do is to add the following line to `$HOME/.netrc`

```
machine github.com login USERNAME password APIKEY
```

- For GitHub accounts, the password can be a [personal access tokens](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/).
- For more information on how to do this, please check Go [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https) page.

Please feel free to leave a comment in case you want more support or help.

Comment: `GOPRIVATE` (`go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/mycompany/*`) is the only thing that worked for me. I might suggest putting that under its own heading or even in an answer of its own to highlight it a bit more.

Comment: For me as well , only `go env -w GOPRIVATE=gitlab.companyname.com`  helped. 
This should be an accepted answer. Thank you for this thorough answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer being thorough. It's saved me on a deadline.

Comment: `export GOPRIVATE=github.com/MyCompanyName/*` is what worked for me.

Comment: export GOPRIVATE=github.com/MyCompanyName/* the only solution here as well, up

Comment: One very important point regarding the `$HOME/.netrc` file is that its persmission shall be `600`.

Answer (score 743):

I found this extremely helpful, and it solved my problem. This command will allow your 2FA to do its thing (and save you the trouble of entering your username and password):

For Github:

```
git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

For Gitlab:

```
git config --global --add url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"
```

Source: http://albertech.blogspot.com/2016/11/fix-git-error-could-not-read-username.html

If you're not using 2FA, you can still use SSH and this will work.

Resulting `.gitconfig` will be like:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Comment: I recommend adding **--add** flag so that you do not overwrite existing settings you may have

For example: `git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"`

Comment: Thanks slatunje, added the flag to my answer based on your feedback.

Comment: This is the best solution IMO. It's more secure and less effort (once setup) to use SSH keys for auth instead of username/password

Comment: Don't do this on Windows. I ended up with error `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`.

Comment: works for linux too. should work for everyone if you're using ssh globaly

Comment: this is great until your company blocks all ssh outbound transport.

Comment: I use bitbucket, so this command helped me: `git config --global --add url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"`

Comment: I'm using windows and now I'm stuck(should spot the warning by @ShitalShah earlier...) any way to undo this?

Comment: So for whoever wondering how to undo this, it will add a section in `C:\Users\<you>\.gitconfig` which you can remove directly

Comment: Worked as expected, but then I had an issue with Xcode being unable to download swift packages. I had to revert this to make it work.

Comment: This will help, BUT. As stated in the release doc of Go 1.13 you should [declare GOPRIVATE variable](https://medium.com/mabar/today-i-learned-fix-go-get-private-repository-return-error-reading-sum-golang-org-lookup-93058a058dd8) when go getting private repositories.

Comment: @CircleHsiao for undo you can edit your .gitconfig

Comment: I've executed the above, my ~/.gitconfig was updated, but I am still getting `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled` when `go get`-ing a private repo ..

Comment: I wonder why we need to use the flag --global here? I tried without it and nothing changed but after added it, things worked like a charm.

Comment: i needed ssh to make this work. Like this:  --add url."ssh://git@github.com:"

Comment: Related official references: https://go.dev/ref/mod#private-module-repo-auth https://go.dev/doc/faq#git_https

Comment: If you're using home manager to configure git: https://gist.github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/5d07dac4a90eb170338df0e11dd3a314

Answer (score 261):

go get disables the "terminal prompt" by default. This can be changed by setting an environment variable of git:

```
env GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 go get github.com/examplesite/myprivaterepo
```

Comment: I've tried all of the top answers here (set environment variable above, update git config using insteadOf, running git clone before go get) and go get is still failing with that issue. Anything else i can try?

Comment: This did the trick: 
go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/{your-github-user-here}/*

Comment: If it helps anyone I copied the `go.mod` and `go.sum` files from another repo and tried to use those. This gave me git login prompts whenever I tried to go `go build` because git kept trying to authenticate to someone else's github repo. 

To fix this you can run `go mod init` and then you should stop seeing these login prompts.

Comment: Thanks @Ferrarezi, that was exactly what I needed. https://www.goproxy.io/docs/GOPRIVATE-env.html explains it.

Comment: I also found the suggestion by @Ferrarezi useful to help solve my similar problem. Thanks Ferrarezi.

Answer (score 49):

1st -- `go get` will refuse to authenticate on the command line. So you need to cache the credentials in git.  Because I use osx I can use osxkeychain credential helper.

2nd For me, I have 2FA enabled and thus could not use my password to auth. Instead I had to generate a personal access token to use in place of the password.

1. setup osxkeychain credential helper https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/
2. If using TFA instead of using your password, generate a personal access token with repo scope https://github.com/settings/tokens
3. git clone a private repo just to make it cache the password     `git clone https://github.com/user/private_repo`   and used your github.com username for username and the generated personal access token for password.
4. Removed the just cloned repo and retest to ensure creds were cached -- `git clone https://github.com/user/private_repo` and this time wasnt asked for creds.

   5. go get will work with any repos that the personal access token can access.  You may have to repeat the steps with other accounts / tokens as permissions vary.

Comment: I have 2FA and this worked for me -- generated a token (with full privs), did a `git clone` of one of my own existing repos (it is public actually), was prompted for my `username`, put in my GitHub username, then put in the generated token for `password` -- deleted the cloned repo, then reran the `go get` command and all was well - thanks! (OSX here as well)

Comment: This is also really great because you can limit the scope of the token to only "read" for private repos so even if it somehow gets into an image in the wild, they can only read your code and not push things into it and you can revoke the token really easily. I can't recall if they have auto expiration built in yet.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Just make sure you have the right permissions when you make the key - I just checked the section for `repo`

Answer (score 30):

Add this is your bash_profile:

```
export GOPRIVATE=github.com/your-organization/*
```

Then run:

```
git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Answer (score 28):

From go 1.13 onwards, if you had already configured your terminal with the git credentials and yet facing this issue, then you could try setting the `GOPRIVATE` environment variable. Setting this environment variable solved this issue for me.

```
export GOPRIVATE=github.com/{organizationName/userName of the package}/*
```

Comment: This is probably the correct answer to the question that the OP **should** have asked.

Comment: This is the only solution which worked for me. :)

Comment: This is the correct answer for go 1.13 or later

Answer (score 24):

If you just want `go get` to work real fast, and move along with your work...

Just export `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1`

```
$ export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
$ go get [whatever]
```

It will now prompt you for a user/pass for the rest of your shell session. Put this in your `.profile` or setup `git` as above for a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 10):

I tried adding this command

> export GOPRIVATE=github.com/{private_reponame}/*

and it worked for me

Comment: I tried all the above options but this one works like a charm. Here is more documentation about it: https://medium.com/mabar/today-i-learned-fix-go-get-private-repository-return-error-reading-sum-golang-org-lookup-93058a058dd8

Answer (score 6):

While there are a lot of answers around using SSH authentication for GitHub, the question pertains to the correct usage for go modules. To this end, Luna Lovegood provides the right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65368910/17737991).

To reiterate, by default Go tries to use a public repository to download packages. We need to specify that it authenticate using SSH for private repos. And to do this, the following can be used:

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/{your-username}/{your-lib}
.
.
go mod vendor     # this will now work for your private lib
```

Glob patterns also work, so if you have multiple private repositories, you can add

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/{your-username}/*
```

Edit: Correct wording.

Comment: I don't think that your last statement is a "regex". It looks like a "glob pattern". Which one is correct? (i.e. if a regex, you probably missed a period, if a pattern, then your statement is incorrect.)

Comment: You are correct @AlexisWilke. What I meant was glob pattern.

Answer (score 5):

If you configure your gitconfig with this option, you will later have a problem cloning other repos of GitHub

```
git config --global --add url. "Git@github.com". Instead, "https://github.com/"
```

Instead, I recommend that you use this option

```
echo "export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1" >> ~/.bashrc || ~/.zshrc
```

and do not forget to generate an access token from your private repository. When prompted to enter your password, just paste the access token. Happy clone :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on windows "error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error" trying to login to github through the login dialog. When I canceled the dialog git asked me for login and password in the command line and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error `terminal prompts disabled` after changing my credentials, Carthage failed to update the dependencies and show this error on terminal.

I just did the simple following steps and it's started working...

1. Remove old credentials from `keychain access`
2. Tried to clone the same repo in different location.
3. It asked for credentials (username + password) to set.
4. And then Carthage update worked as before.

Answer (score 1):

If the repo is private and needs authentication. Where you need to pass your credentials. The below command would help

```
 git config --global --add url.https://YOUR_USER_NAME:YOUR_GIT_TOKEN@gitswarm.YOUR_HOST.com.insteadof https://gitswarm.YOUR_HOST.com
```

DOC to create a [token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add the credentials as part of the URL.

To access a repository on GitLab, for example, I use this format for the URL:

`https://<user>:<access-token>@<gitlab-server>/<path-to-repo>.git`

Answer (score 0):

Try this cmd:

```
GO111MODULE=on GOSUMDB=off go get github.com/examplesite/myprivaterepo
```

Or:

```
go clean -modcache
go get github.com/examplesite/myprivaterepo
```

Answer (score -2):

I get to understand that to save time with GitHub it helps to download it CLI `gh`

with it there is auth command which i used and it make my life easier

```bash
gh auth login
```