# Error when cloning private git repository with yarn

Tags: git, yarnpkg

I have a project and want to get all dependecies with yarn on Linux. When I use

```
yarn install
```

I am getting the following error:

```
#yarn install
yarn install v0.27.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: clone http://example.org/git/my_example.git /usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v1/.tmp/05a8813322130c7dd3080dc68b6c6680
Directory: /home/user/my_project
Output:
Clone to '/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v1/.tmp/05a8813322130c7dd3080dc68b6c6680' ...
fatal: could not read Username for 'http://example.org': terminal prompts  disabled
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

The link at the end doesn't helped. I searched a little bit and set the environment variable `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT` before executing the command:

```
env GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 yarn install
```

like proposed here: [go get results in 'terminal prompts disabled' error for github private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232655/go-get-results-in-terminal-prompts-disabled-error-for-github-private-repo)

The use of the credential cache doesn't work because I have not a cloned repository, this should be cloned by yarn.

But the result is the same. What can I do to get this issue working?

Comment: Is `http://example.org`... the actual link you're using, or did you change it in the question?

Comment: Did you try using an ssh endpoint instead of the http one?

Comment: That is currently not possible as this doesn't support our git server (we have one under Windows which serves the repositories via IIS).

Comment: I've worked around this by using the following `"package-name": "git+https://<github_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28729646/5199198