# Receiving fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled while building project in terminal

Tags: git

I have started working on Golang project. While building with make, I am getting following error:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

To handle this, I have done following after going through similar post [go get results in 'terminal prompts disabled' error for github private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232655/go-get-results-in-terminal-prompts-disabled-error-for-github-private-repo) :

```
export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
```

But this did not solve the problem, now it seems to be asking username and password in infinite loop.

My git config is as follows:

```
$git config --list

remote.origin.url=git@github.com:GolangProjects/Project1.git
```

Even after this config, why it keeps on using https instead of SSH, not getting any clue. Please help.

Comment: Does your Makefile contain any invocations of `git` or any program that might use it, like a package manager?  Do you have any submodules in your project?

Comment: Yes as part of build, it pulls and installs go dependencies.

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve]. What commands do you run from your Makefile?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Create an SSH key instead and use it as a default login method for you git repo.
You can follow this link to create an ssh key for authentication on your machine:

[Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.17/user/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

And then use this to default your login method to use ssh keys instead of your credentials:

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

Comment: A word of warning to Mac/iOS developers - the above global git config will fix things on the command line but will break Git in Xcode.

Comment: do you have a solution that wont? I am currently suffering this issue with fastlane.

Answer (score 4):

Is one of your imports from a private repo?

If so, you need to let Go know about it.

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/mycompany/*
```

or

```
export GOPRIVATE=*.corp.example.com,github.com/mycompany/*
```

(I had the same problem, and took this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60323360/20837494

Comment: This looks like effectively the same answer as the linked one https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/346302

Comment: So what am I supposed to do? should I report the question as a duplicate, instead of putting in an answer?

Comment: I tend to link to the answer in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with `git fetch`:

```
Fetching the repository
  /usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin +refs/heads/master*:refs/remotes/origin/master* +refs/tags/master*:refs/tags/master*
  Error: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
  The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
  Waiting 14 seconds before trying again
```

To fix that you have to update the repo `secrets` token.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I had the same issue on GitHub Actions, and the issue was resolved after I updated the variable for the Personal Access Token (PAT).

Comment: This is correct answer, if you get this message your PAT probably expired and you new to issue new one.