# Receiving "could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled" when installing packages in Cloudbuild

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-build

This is part of my `package.json` dependencies obj:

```
"api-helper": "git+https://github.com/MyCorp/api-helper#fe371092da29e4b4bc331196b7ef86a76a037a05",
"logger": "git+https://github.com/MyCorp/logger#ddb409b2d69c5bd1adbab87fd415ddd14414e326",
"utils": "git+https://github.com/MyCorp/utils#a7f9cff3e98438350f76086329eb0d16f001641f",
"stats-module": "git+https://github.com/MyCorp/stats-module#v0.0.2"
```

All of these packages are, as you can see, private packages in my company's GitHub Org. The newest one that I've added, the `stats-module`, fails the CI build at `yarn install` step with the following error:

```
could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

If I remove the `stats-module` the packages are installed successfully.
I tried also using the git sha instead of a version, the same way the other packages are, but that makes no difference. And obviously everything works well locally.

And there is no difference in the github repo access permissions between the `stats-module` and the other 3 private repos. I'm really clueless at what might be the issue.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure why you are getting this error but you could try the same strategy that is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803903/7757976). Those commands could be run in the Dockerfile used by your Cloud Build.