# Invalid version and https references when importing private repo in golang

Tags: git, go

Trying to import a private repo as package in golang. Did:

```
git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

So in theory all references to https are replaced by the ssh version.

```
github.com/XXX/util
```

Is my private repo which is a go module.

I do a go get -v and get:

```
[gabriel@xiridio backend]$ go get -v
go: finding module for package github.com/XXX/util
go: downloading github.com/XXX/util v0.0.0-20200411022955-454673685ff5
go: finding module for package github.com/XXX/util
main.go:12:2: github.com/XXX/util@v0.0.0-20200411022955-454673685ff5: verifying module: github.com/XXX/util@v0.0.0-20200411022955-454673685ff5: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/!X!X!X/util@v0.0.0-20200411022955-454673685ff5: 410 Gone
        server response:
        not found: github.com/XXX/util@v0.0.0-20200411022955-454673685ff5: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/f1fdc5cc42a6995f954688df06783c05d28e4a60e9aaf6930a88a2487b913907: exit status 128:
                fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Looks like  there is a "version" issue and also for some reason there is still references to https. What else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be sure, I prefer using quotes for the git config command:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

See this [gist as an example](https://gist.github.com/dmitshur/6927554).

It includes:

> An alternative to using `git@github.com` is to generate a personal access token on your GitHub account, grant it repo access, and then use the following instead:
>
> ```
> git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
> ```

Check also "[`go get` results in 'terminal prompts disabled' error for GitHub private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60323360/6309)", which mentions the use of `GOPRIVATE`.

Comment: Thank you. Using the git config AND the GOPRIVATE worked.

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla which of the two `git config` did you used?

Comment: The quotes did not have any influence on the output to ~/.gitconfig, so both are valid.

Answer (score 4):

There were 2 things I had to do to be able to pull my private modules using `go 1.18`:

1. equivalent to @VonC 's answer, added the following 2 lines to my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

2. explicitly added *each* of my private module git paths to the GOPRIVATE variable:

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE="github.com/projname/mod1,github.com/projname/mod2,github.com/projname/mod3"
```

i believe this is both necessary and sufficient, or at least sufficient.

> *note* that you will need to have local access to your private repos with ssh for this to work.