# fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': terminal prompts disabled

Tags: git, docker, go, package, gitlab

I am trying to build docker image for go app that is  using different go packages from different private gitlab repos. When I was doing it on my local machine, I had to add the following commands in order to make it work;

```sh
git config --global url.git@gitlab.com:.insteadOf https://gitlab.com/
export GOPRIVATE=*gitlab*
```

In this case, my ssh key will be used and it worked fine.

Now, I want to do the same thing when building a Docker image but without using ssh keys so I though of using deployment token (the token has access for all repos in the gitlab group).

dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.14 AS builder

...

ARG USER
ARG KEY

RUN git config --global url."https://${USER}:${KEY}@gitlab.com/".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"
RUN export GOPRIVATE=*gitlab*
```

apparently, this didn't work and I become the following error:

```
Fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Can you please share your ideas on how I could make it work using deployment tokens?

Comment: are `${USER}` and `${KEY}` set as build-args during build ?

Comment: yes, I build it like this: ```docker build --build-arg USER=$GITLAB_DOCKER_USER --build-arg KEY=$GITLAB_DOCKER_KEY -t go-dns . ```

Comment: is `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT` set ? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237165/2087704

Comment: yes, like this ```RUN export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1```

Comment: What does `RUN git config credential.helper` returns on `docker build`?

Comment: @VonC I am getting an error ```Step 8/24 : RUN git config credential.helper
 ---> Running in 956bb736901d
The command '/bin/sh -c git config credential.helper' returned a non-zero code: 1```

Comment: @Kingindanord Sorry, try `RUN git config --global credential.helper`

Comment: @VonC same result
```Step 8/23 : RUN git config --global credential.helper
 ---> Running in 5412c2440f1e
The command '/bin/sh -c git config --global credential.helper' returned a non-zero code: 1```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As workaround, I clone the repo(s) manually and then edit `go mod` file

```
RUN git clone https://${USER}:${KEY}@gitlab.com/mygroup/myproject
RUN go mod init gitlab.com/mygroup/go-dns
RUN go mod edit -replace=gitlab.com/mygroup/myproject=./myproject
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario the issue with this error message:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Despite me having:

1. configured correctly SSH keys for GitLab / Git,
2. and invoked globally `git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"`

was that:

- the `go` command for some reason clones some repositories (not all repositories) at "root path" `/tmp/...`,
- but the Git global config refers to the `$HOME` directory.

The solution for me was to add as prefix the `GOPRIVATE` env var to the `go command like this:

```
GOPRIVATE=gitlab.com/my-org-name go mod download
```

Bear in mind that despite not having setup a `GOPATH` env var, my recent Go installation has a `GOPATH` setup by default that I can see from `go env` which points at `$HOME/go/`,
see the different output from the `env` command and the `go env` command here:

```bash
$ env | grep GOPATH
$ go env | grep -i path
GOPATH="/home/<<MY_USER>>/go"
```

This above means that commands like `go mod download` start pulling repos from GitLab and store them in various places:

1. your local Go module (as expected),
2. this "special" `go env` based default `GOPATH` pointing at `/home/<<MY_USER>>/go`
3. this even "more special" path `/tmp/...`

This weird combination of paths might be part of the issue when not using `GOPRIVATE`