# Docker-Compose - Import private repositories in go test

Tags: git, docker, go, docker-compose, gitlab

I just ran into a super weird issue and I really don't get what's currently happening..

I had a project while some e2e tests, everything was working fine. For some reason, I had to use some privates repositories (from gitlab) of mine as I developed some layers related to databases and others purposes.

The thing is, when I tried to run `go test` from docker compose command, it's now failing with the following message:

```
e2e_tests_1 | FAIL       gitlab.com/foo-bar-group/awesome-api/tests/e2e [setup failed]
e2e_tests_1 | # gitlab.com/foo-bar-group/awesome-api/tests/e2e
e2e_tests_1 | internal/domain/models/file_infos.go:7:2: gitlab.com/emixam23-generic-utils/google-cloud-storage@vxxx: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/xxx: exit status 128:
e2e_tests_1 |    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': terminal prompts disabled
e2e_tests_1 | FAIL
```

I have a simple docker compose that runs 3 containers (mongodb, elasticsearch, custom golang docker image). My Dockerfile has a small script which help me (and which is working) to know when everything is ready for a full test

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.17.6

WORKDIR /app

ENV GO111MODULE on

# Download wait for it tool.
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it
```

**docker-compose.tests-e2e.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  mongodb_e2e_tests:
    image: mongo:5.0.4

  elasticsearch_e2e_tests:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.0
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"

  e2e_tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.e2e_tests
    environment:
      # ...
    depends_on:
      - mongodb_e2e_tests
      - elasticsearch_e2e_tests
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: sh -c "/wait-for-it elasticsearch_e2e_tests:9200 -- /wait-for-it mongodb_e2e_tests:27017 -- go test ./tests/e2e/... -p 1 -v -count=1"
```

Everything seems to work as before, until the `go test ./tests/e2e/... -p 1 -v -count=1` which from now on, at *go get* time, cannot fetch my private repository...

Thanks for any help.. I really did search to inject SSH, so setup git and everything but.. It seems to have something to do with docker-compose... not my Dockerfile image or my golang command

Thanks again..

Best,

Max

Comment: ssh key based auth is what you want, then it will 'just work' for Go.  If you run go build in docker compose, https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/build-secrets-and-ssh-forwarding-in-docker-18-09-ae8161d066 can help you safely and securely expose ssh credentials for git authnz.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237165/4486909

> `go get` disables the "terminal prompt" by default.
> This can be changed by setting an environment variable of git:
> `env GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1`

Try to add the following vars to your docker-compose `env` section:
`GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1`

Additionally, you could get a go with this one:
`TERM=xterm`