# gitlab privilege issue when running go mod tidy on Windows 11

Tags: go, gitlab

I am able to do clone, push and other git commands very well (must be stored in credential manager in windows). But issue appear when I execute `go mod tidy`

Below is the error I got when executing `go mod tidy` on my windows machine. Looks like no access to private repository.

```
gitlab.xxxxx.de/cxxxxs-v2/arc-lib/cxxxxs-go-lib/pkg/clients:
gitlab.xxxx.de/cxxxxs-v2/arc-lib/cxxxxs-go-lib@v1.10.1: verifying
module: gitlab.xxxx.de/cxxxxs-v2/arc-lib/cxxxxs-go-lib@v1.10.1:
reading
https://sum.golang.org/lookup/gitlab.xxxxx.de/cxxxxs-v2/arc-lib/cxxxxs-go-lib@v1.10.1:
404 Not Found
    server response:
    not found: gitlab.xxxxx.de/cxxxxs-v2/arc-lib/cxxxxs-go-lib@v1.10.1: invalid
version: git ls-remote -q origin in
/tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/387e08be1426cc3d2399d471d4c4b55445c31d6ca639398a03889c4c3282d1d5:
exit status 128:
            fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.xxxxx.de': terminal prompts disabled
    Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
    If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

I have created the `HOME` env variables, pointing to same folder as `USERPROFILE`.

Also created `_netrc` file with machine, username and password.
Same username and password used in web gitlab login, it works fine.

`_netrc` content :

```
machine gitlab.aaaaaa.de
login ranjit.kumar
password *****
```

I am not able to figure out how to debug this to find rootcause and hence the solution. Please guide me on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [go get results in 'terminal prompts disabled' error for github private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232655/go-get-results-in-terminal-prompts-disabled-error-for-github-private-repo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/gitlab.xxxxx.de/cidaas-v2/arc-lib/cidaas-go-lib@v1.10.1: 404 Not Found

It tries to lookup your private module in the Go SUMDB. Since your module is private, it's not there.

You should add the glob pattern of your private module to `GOPRIVATE`. Do it like this:

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=gitlab.xxxxx.de
```

`GOPRIVATE` acts as a default value for `GONOPROXY` and `GONOSUMDB`. It tells the go tool to download the module from the private repository directly (`GONOPROXY`) and not to check the module using the public checksum database (`GONOSUMDB`).

See [Private modules](https://go.dev/ref/mod#private-modules) for more information.

---

BTW, you don't need to set `_netrc` if you can fetch or push to the repository without it. And setting the `HOME` environment variable seems irrelevant too.